# MVVM listbox item contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a problem with binding contextmenu of listbox item. After build my contextmenu won´t display any item. I have searched a lot but without any positive result. Contextmenu is still empty. Do you know any solution for my problem please?

Thanks for help.

Listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="uxTrendListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding SignalGroup.Trends}" SelectedIndex="0" DisplayMemberPath="TrendName" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTrend}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Normal" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="white" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10" Background="#FF5B5A5A">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding CommandList}">
                            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Displayname}" Command="{Binding ContextMenuCommand}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox >
```

CommandList:

```
private ObservableCollection<ContextMenuAction> commandList = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuAction>();
        public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuAction> CommandList
        {
            get
            {
                return commandList;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(ref commandList, value);
            }
        }
```

Command list filling in constructor of ViewModel class:

```
 CommandList.Add(new ContextMenuAction
        {
            Displayname = "Rename trend",
            ContextMenuCommand = TrendRenameCommand
        });
        CommandList.Add(new ContextMenuAction
        {
            Displayname = "Remove trend", 
            ContextMenuCommand = TrendRemoveCommand
        });
```

ContextMenuAction class:

```
 public class ContextMenuAction : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string displayName;

    public string Displayname
    {
        get { return displayName; }
        set
        {
            displayName = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Displayname"));
        }
    }

    private ICommand contextMenuCommand;

    public ICommand ContextMenuCommand
    {
        get { return contextMenuCommand; }
        set
        {
            contextMenuCommand = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ContextMenuCommand"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start Debugging application by pressing f5. navigate to the page and show context menu to reproduce the error while debugging
2. Check your output window for binding errors (`Menu->Debug->Windows->Output`). If you have error in binding, you should see it here
3. where did you defined the `CommandList` property? It should be on your `Trend' class or whatever you call it
4. Why do you have public setter on your `CommandList` property, when you create instance of the observable collection in field initializer?
   This is probably not cousing the issue, but usually you either only Add/Remove items from the collection, or you dont modify the collection but always set new instance of the collection. Your class allows both, and that smells a litte